400 error code for calling /api/GetExternalShares for some SharePoint sites using O365 connector
We are trying to integrate SharePoint Online using O365 connector but for some sites we are getting 400 error code.
Calling REST webservice : https://IP:Port/api/GetExternalShares

Webservice call failed Url-https://IP:PORT/api/GetExternalShares,
apiRequestDetails-{siteColUrl":"https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite"
HTTP error code : 400 Error Message: O365 Connector Exception: Object
reference not set to an instance of an object.""


Currently SharePoint Rest doesn't support such API. You could use graph api to get external sharing
GET /shares/{shareIdOrEncodedSharingUrl}

Here is the document for reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
